# combine multiple DTDs into one or reuse common part

Tags: xml, libxml2, dtd

I have lots of external DTDs for different XML document types. All of the DTDs are very similar: include common DTD definitions and then 5-10 lines of the document type specific definitions which rely the common definitions. Though the specific definitions are short, the common definitions are large.

Is it possible somehow to combine all this small external DTDs into a single one large DTD?

The specific problem I have is the overhead of DTD parsing. First idea was to cache the parsed DTDs. Yet the idea has failed because, as I have found out, every single of the DTDs (with libxml2 v2.9.2) takes ~1.1MB of RAM: multiplied by ~25, the number of the DTDs, that is way above our memory limit. Since 99% of the DTDs are actually the same common definitions, I'm looking for the ways to somehow reuse the common part.

Answer (score 0):

(Replying to myself.)

> Is it possible somehow to combine all this small external DTDs into a single one large DTD?

That seems to be impossible. I haven't found any official means to accomplish that.

The libxml2 also doesn't seem to provide any non-standard facilities to accomplish that.

> I'm looking for the ways to somehow reuse the common part.

Analyzing the problem in depth, with the help of libxml2, I have found 2 possibilities.

1. Optimize the DTD. After loading the DTD, the includes/entities are expanded, and DTD becomes a flat list of sub-nodes (elements, entities ,attributes, etc), anchored at the DTD node. Starting with the top-level node (corresponding to the DOCTYPE) one can derive the list of the DTD sub-nodes which are actually used(+), and delete everything which is not used. Then, using the dumping function, once can write the remaining entries into a new DTD file, which now should be much smaller than the original. ((+) Though deep introspection of the DTD sub-nodes doesn't seem to be supported, it is still possible to extract the information from the string-ified representation of the node.)
2. Dynamically compose the DTD in memory from the common and the document type specific definitions. Looking through the libxml2 API I have found a function which allows to extend the parsed DTD in memory: `xmlAddElementDecl()` and `xmlAddAttributeDecl()`. The API seems to be rudimentary. But at the very least, it seems to be possible to: load the common part; load the document type specific part; temporarily, with the help of the functions, move (or copy) the sub-nodes from the later to the former. After the move, the DTD structure in the memory should be nearly identical to that of the original DTD. Later, after the validation was performed, one can move back (or free the copies of) the sub-nodes, to make the (large) common part reusable again.

Unfortunately, at the moment I had no time to test neither of the approaches in practice.